# How to earth connector with plastic case

Tags: grounding, earth

My board has a power connector from Glenair 171-006. Input is 5V DC. This connector has a plastic case. My question is, can I use one of the connector contacts to connect to EARTH? Will it cause any issues? 
Should I use one or two contacts to connect to EARTH?

Comment: Notice that a a 3-prong mains plug has one of its conductors used for an earth connection without issues.

Answer (score 0):

One (1) contact may be sufficient depending on current.

- Reliability or type of connection may be a consideration.

  ( hot insertion types need Protruding ground contact first)

Each contact is only rated for 3A.

You cannot ground the plastic. (! ?)

[image]

Comment: IIRC protective earthing is required to be connected before any of the mains power lines can connect, **regardless** if the connection is meant to be hot-insertion capable or not. Because, it may loosen itself and do a hot-fail. If this is shielding only, meh.

Comment: yes but Question is vague about other requirements. Probably not a IEC approved product with AC input due to lack of insight in question.

Comment: Input is 5V DC. There will not be any hot insertion. In case of ESD or lightning event, will it disrupt circuit or couple nearby power/digital ground contacts.

Comment: maybe.... inputs may need shielding and filtering maybe clamping and surge current limiting.. or not.. it all depends on the details